# Save ppm in Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, jpeg, ppm

I'm newbie using images in Android and I need some hel saving an image in ppm format.
I'm using OpenCV to capture an image in byte[] format. I know how to save it in .jpg but I need to save it in .ppm instead

There ([Android GIMP JPG to PPM conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908635/android-gimp-jpg-to-ppm-conversion)) I read something about creat a Bitmap an drop the Alpha channel, but as I said, I'm newbie using images in Android and I can't find any documentation that help me